# How does SCM restarts a service?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service

When a restart command given to a service in the windows service console, which step SCM performs?

1. OnStop() and OnStart(), Or
2. require Restart implementation, Or
3. OnStop() --> Dspose() --> C'tr (new instance) and OnStart() ?

Comment: The SCM sends a stop control, waits for the service to stop, and then restarts it.  This might or might not result in the process exiting and a new process being started, your code has to be able to cope with both scenarios.  In the case where the process doesn't exit, I don't know for sure whether ServiceBase creates a new instance of your class object or not, though since your code is responsible for creating the first instance it would seem inconsistent for ServiceBase to create new ones.

Comment: (Note that the SCM doesn't know anything about ServiceBase or the OnStart and OnStop methods.  As far as it is concerned, a .NET service is just the same as any other service, the implementation details don't matter.)